# Event Brite QR code

Tags: qr-code, eventbrite

I've dug through the methods in Event Brite API but can't find any reference to QR codes generated by Eventbrite in their native IOS app.

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/#methods

without reverse engineering it or sniffing the web urls - can anyone shed some light on how to do this?

Comment: What do these QR codes point to? Is it the EventBrite page, or is it a "ticket" which can be scanned when the user attends the event?

Comment: I can understand the security implications of allowing access to this. But I just need to qr codes for purchased / free tickets from current event owner. we sold them / or gave them away. Why shouldn't the API give access to them?

Comment: So you want to get the QR which appears on the ticket? Do you have a sample code to see what data is encoded in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventbrite barcode information is a sensitive issue - but, Eventbrite is happy to discuss specifics [over email](http://developer.eventbrite.com/contact-us/)

If you just want to build a list of QR codes for the current event owner, you should be able to generate them from the barcode_ids returned from the [event_list_attendees](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/) API call.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I'm trying to use the Eventbrite barcodes to check visitors in.  @johndpope - did you get any further in your quest?

The codes on each ticket are not QR Codes, but Datamatrix (for reading by the iOS/Android app) and Code 128 (I think).  Both codes on the ticket (and incidently, the QR Code on Conferencebadge.com's app) are simply numeric and take the following form...

{OrderID}{AttendeeID}{Seq}

for example

123456789 123456789 001  (no spaces)

Any bit of barcode generating code can recreate these, but checking people in without an API method is a bit harder.  The iOS/Android app rightly uses HTTPS and you need to be authenticated to the website to use the checkin_update URL used by the website.

Comment: I actually flew over to San Francisco. Ryan was very helpful. It's best to talk to them.

Comment: Thanks @johndpope. I received an email back from Brian Zambrano at Eventbrite saying that (a) it's not yet possible to check in via the API and (b) a updated API is due this year with much more functionality. Fingers crossed!